# In Wrath of the Righteous, does the light spell hinder sneaking?

Tags: pathfinder-wrath-of-the-righteous

Around a table, a D&D Dungeon Master will give little chance to a thief willing to sneak or to attempt a stealth attack, if his companions are using a light spell just in front of him.

But what about *Wrath of the Righteous*, the computer game?

At the beginning of a game, the tutorial recommend to use that light spell,
without warning that it can hinder sneaking abilities.

Does the light spell hinder sneaking in wotr computer game?

Comment: Can you rephrase this to state plainly exactly the problem you're having and the question you have? Like, ditch the first two paragraphs, let's just talk about the computer game. What do you mean “does the light spell effectively troubles them”? Do you mean, like, does the light spell hinder sneaking?